# How to use multiplication in limit clause in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want multiply two numbers in LIMIT level in request but it gives me an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(5-1),10' at line 1

here is the request:

```
SELECT * FROM POSITIONS LIMIT (5*1),10
```

Comment: Well first try `(5*1)` as `(5-1)` is a subtraction not a multiplication although that probably wont work either

Comment: post edited thank u for the remarque

Comment: yes it doesnt work..i dont know why

Comment: Was this solved? If yes then can you tell what query you used for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) it appears that Limit must be a constant value.

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

This would limit you from being able to do math as part of the value.  The prepared statements exception would allow you to use a parameter, where you did the calculation before and used an integer parameter to represent the limit, not sure if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to MySQL version 5.5.6, your only option is to used a prepared statement:

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=5;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

After versions 5.5.6, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) states:
"Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6."